# Limiting input to A-Z with a max of 20 characters

Tags: python-3.x, input, while-loop, append, character

I have this code that allows people to input destinations and it appends to a list:

```
i=0
while 1:
    i+=1
    place=input('Enter Extra Destination %d: '%i)
    if place != '':
        print ('Press enter to stop')
    if place=='':
        break
    dest.append(place)
```

Id like to limit the destination input to A-Z (upper and lower case) and max of 20 characters. Im not sure how to. I know how to limit to numbers but not text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[str.isalpha()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isalpha.htm) only accepts alphabet characters. Note that spaces aren't allowed, though.

To limit to only alphabet characters *with spaces* and max of 20 characters:

```
if string.replace(" ", "").isalpha() and len(string) <= 20:
    # what you want to do
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

`.replace(" ", "").isalpha()` removes all whitespace before checking, so spaces will be allowed

Comment: It doesnt seem to work in the code i have at the momment. Do you suggest any way to integrate it?

Comment: @aNameNoob: Ah, I have made an edit with correct code. I realized that `.split()` trims only leading and trailing whitespace, not all whitespace.

Comment: thanks, ive managed to get the other code to work, will make those changes

Answer (score 1):

kind of ugly, but a join with a list comprehension and a check using isalpha or a space is a good demo

```
>>> a = 'abcdefg hijk @ 123 cdezyxwvu'
>>> "".join([i for i in a if i.isalpha() or i==" "])[:20]
'abcdefg hijk   cdezy'
```